# Unable to satisfy basic constraints done programmatically in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I've been working on trying to satisfy some basic constraints and am not having any luck. I've worked with constraints before and this *should* seem to work. I'm not sure if it's an Apple issue because I've run into other questions with constraints in which it was, however the solutions I followed didn't solve the issue.

Here is the code I'm running:

UITableViewController viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;
```

TestTableViewCell init:

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {

    self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    self.mainTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.mainTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    [self.mainTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.mainTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:32 saturation:100 brightness:63 alpha:1]];
    [self.mainTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:18.0f]];
    self.mainTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.mainTextLabel];

    [self setupConstraints];
}
return self;
```

TestTableViewCell setting up constraints:

```
- (void)setupConstraints {

NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"textLabel":self.mainTextLabel};

NSArray *mainHorizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[textLabel]-20-|"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:viewsDictionary];
[self.contentView addConstraints:mainHorizontalConstraints];


NSArray *mainVerticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[textLabel]-20-|"
                                                                           options:0
                                                                           metrics:nil
                                                                             views:viewsDictionary];
[self.contentView addConstraints:mainVerticalConstraints];
```

The error message received:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
```

I'm just setting up basic top, bottom, leading, and trailing constraints and the constraints are breaking. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why you give constrain programically of your tableview item . show UI of your Tableview

Comment: Try setting the property "setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints" to false for the tableViewCell.

Comment: @Rikh set "setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints" to false and the constraints are still breaking

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I'm doing the constraints programmatically because I'm working with legacy code

Comment: @MichaelLeech please update your question with one screen shot so easily get idea what kind of constrain you programmatically perform.

Comment: [self.tableview setNeedsLayout];
[self.tableview layoutIfNeeded]; try this 2 line perform your constrain.

Comment: How are the constraints breaking exactly?

Comment: The only two problems I see with the above code is that (a) you didn't set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` for `mainTextLabel`, as discussed elsewhere; and (b) you're setting `setBackgroundColor` with HSBA values greater than 1.0 ... all of those values should be between 0.0 and 1.0. But I used your code (with the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`) and it worked. You should edit your question and share the precise error message.

Comment: can you create a demo project with your uitableviewcell int git and share, then i can set the constraints

Comment: When you say "constraints are breaking", can you be more specific?

Comment: @Rob Setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false on mainTextLabel fixed it. I was setting it on the table cell. Thank you. Will post the error message and answer if anyone else runs into the same issue.

Comment: Thanks to everyone else who left a comment

Answer (score 0):

Setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO on the mainTextLabel fixes the issue.